# App Engine: Keep Socket Open more than 2 Minutes

Tags: java, google-app-engine, sockets

Using the App Engine Trusted Tester Sockets to connect to APNS. Writing to socket works fine.

But the problem is that the Socket gets reclaimed after 2 minutes of inactivity. It says in the Trusted Tester Website that any socket operation keeps the socket alive for further 2 minutes. It is nicer to keep the socket open until APNS decides to close the connection.

After trying pretty much all of the Socket API methods short of writing to the Output Stream, Socket gets closed after 2 minutes no matter what. What have I missed?

Deployed on java backend.

Answer (score 1):

You can't keep a socket connected to APNS artifically open; without sending actual push notifications. The only way to keep it open is to send some arbitrary data/bytes but that would result in an immediate closure of the socket; APNS closes the connection as soon as it detects something that does not conform to the protocol, i.e. something that is not an actual push notification.

`SO_KEEPALIVE`

What about `SO_KEEPALIVE`? App Engine explicitly says it is supported. I think it just means it won't throw an exception when you call `Socket.setKeepAlive(true)`; calls wanted to set socket options raised Not Implemented exceptions before. Even if you enable keep-alive your socket will be reclaimed (closed) if you don't send something for more than 2 minutes; at least on App Engine as of now.

Actually, it's not a big surprise. [RFC1122](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc1122#page-101) that specifies TCP Keep Alive explicitly states that TCP Keep Alives are not to be sent more than once every two hours, and then, it is only necessary if there was no other traffic. Although, it also says that this interval must be also configurable, there is no API on `java.net.Socket` you could use to configure that (most probably because it's highly OS dependent) and I doubt it would be set to 2 minutes on App Engine.

`SO_TIMEOUT`

What about `SO_TIMEOUT`? It is for something completely else. The javadoc of `Socket.setSoTimeout()` states:

> Enable/disable SO_TIMEOUT with the specified timeout, in milliseconds. With this option set to a non-zero timeout, a read() call on the InputStream associated with this Socket will block for only this amount of time. If the timeout expires, a java.net.SocketTimeoutException is raised, though the Socket is still valid. The option must be enabled prior to entering the blocking operation to have effect. The timeout must be > 0. A timeout of zero is interpreted as an infinite timeout.

That is, when `read()` is blocking for too long because there's nothing to read you can say "ok, I don't want to wait (block) anymore; let's do something else instead". It's not going to help with our "2 minutes" problem.

`What then?`

The only way you can work around this problem is this: detect when a connection is reclaimed/closed then throw it away and open a new connection. And there is a library which supports exactly that.

Check out `java-apns-gae`.

It's an open-source Java APNS library that was specifically designed to work (and be used) on Google App Engine.

https://github.com/ZsoltSafrany/java-apns-gae

Answer (score 0):

Did you try getSoLinger()?  That may be the getSocketOpt that works (kind of) currently and it may reset the 2 minute timeout.  In theory, also doing a zero byte read would as well but I'm not sure that would, if you try that, use this method on the inputstream.

public int read(byte b[], int off, int len)

If these suggestions don't work, please file an issue with the App Engine issue tracker.

There will be some other fixes coming, e.g. using socket options etc.

Comment: Thanks for the response. I did try read(new byte[0]) but it didn't work, is this the same as doing read(_,0,0)? I did try #setSoTimeout and it didn't work. Is this the same as doing the #setSoLinger.

Comment: Is this still broken for you?

Comment: I don't have access to GAE anymore. When I do, I'll recheck this. So far none of the methods on Sockets did anything for the timeout.

Comment: For me it still closes on GAE after circa 2 minutes - I do use socket.setKeepAlive(true) but it doesn't help. Btw, setSoTimeout(..) is for something else: the timeout period is used when calling the read/write methods to stop blocking after the timeout (by throwing a timeout exception).

Answer (score 0):

Use `getpeername()`.

From https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/sockets/overview ...

> Sockets may be reclaimed after 2 minutes of inactivity; **any socket
>   operation (e.g. getpeername) keeps the socket alive for a further 2
>   minutes**. (Notice that you cannot Select between multiple available
>   sockets because that requires java.nio.SocketChannel which is not
>   currently supported.)